# Ruby/Rails: Obtain list of all available imap folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

I am new to Ruby/Rails and have been looking at Net::IMAP. What I would like to do is connect to my IMAP account and iterate over all of my IMAP folders. If I use my ISP's webmail client I see that all of my folders exist under a single mailbox named, 'INBOX'.

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(@server_name, @server_port)
imap.login(@username, @password)

imap.select("INBOX")

# obtain a list of mailboxes contained within INBOX
all_folders = imap.list('', 'INBOX/%')
# all_folders is always set to nil
```

I've tried various permutations for the params to Net::IMAP#list method. What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, what you can try is to use * instead of %.

```
% is a wildcard for everything besides hierarchical characters.
* also includes hierarchical characters.

You should get back an array of IMAP::MailboxList
```

You can also try:

```
imap.list('*', '*')  to see a list of folders.
```

The code provided by you should work, however different mail providers have different implementations, so knowing which one you are using, might help figuring this out.

Comment: Thank you! I have been very surprised to learn that so many aspects of imap seem to be client/server dependent (gmail's imap works differently than my ISP's (dreamhost) functionality. Any documentation pointers would be much appreciated - I've been looking at the RFCs, but again, so many things seem to disregard the RFCs.

Comment: RFC 3501 is a good start, and everything follows that to some extent. Gmail is an IMAP /gateway/, and is attempting to adapt features that don't exist in IMAP (like labels).

Comment: Also, if you want absolutely all folders, you want `imap.list('', '*')`, first parameter is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

For Net::IMAP version 2.0.3 right way is:

`imap.list('%', '%')`